# MySQL SELECT query WHERE "something is TRUE"

Tags: mysql

I have a "users" table in my database, unfortunately there is a lot of mess in it and I try to move it to new one. But just exact things not copy / paste whole.

Here is example how db looks like:

```
    -------*/*------------*/*------------*/*------------*/*------------*/*------------
      id        level          name           kind         status          parentId
    -------*/*------------*/*------------*/*------------*/*----------*/*------------
    EMD123F |     2        |   OrgName1   |     Org      |            |  rootID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DHAD781 |     3        |   UserName1  |    Person    |   active   |  EMD123F 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    7AJIZU7 |     3        |   UserName2  |    Person    |   active   |  EMD123F 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DME123F |     2        |   OrgName2   |     Org      |            |  rootID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TT5451AL|     3        |   UserName3  |    Person    |   active   |  DME123F 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RRMI7481|     2        |   OrgName3   |     Org      |            |  rootID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PPUNSAD9|     2        |   OrgName4   |     Org      |            |  rootID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GJASDNZB|     3        |   UserName4  |    Person    |  inactive  |  PPUNSAD9
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KJNSCZM7|     2        |   OrgName5   |     Org      |            |  rootID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1UZGOPAS|     3        |   UserName5  |    Person    |   deleted  |  KJNSCZM7
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What you see here that there are some "Organizations" which have 0 users so are absolutley useless, there are some organizations which have users but they are not active ( inactive , deleted... ).

My question is how to write a select statement to get ALL ORGANIZATION WHERE there is atelast 1 active person inside of it.

RealData is a bit more complicated but I try something like this:

```
UPDATE users set org_status=1 WHERE (select count(STATUS) FROM users WHERE users.MEMBERKIND="Person" AND users.STATUS="Active" AND users.ROOTORGANIZATIONUSERID= users.ROOTORGANIZATIONIDCORRECTED)>0 AND MEMBERKIND = "Organization" AND LEVEL=2
```

I create new row "org_status" and set it to NULL and after that I try to update it

Comment: Pleas provide the query/queries you have tried so far. But a subselect should work, I guess (untested): `SELECT * FROM orgaTable WHERE (select count(*) from orgaTable AS users WHERE users.parentId = orgaTable.id) > 0;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join your_table t2 on t2.parentId = t1.id
where t2.status = 'active'
```

Comment: Hey, I am sorry if I confuse you but there is not 2 tables, it's just one atm

Comment: Yes. I join the same table (`your_table`) twice in the query with different alias names `t1` and `t2`

Comment: Hey, thanks for point , I try it multiple times unfortunately I wasn't able to get succesfull result. I get only 24 rows rest few thousands are lost.

Logicaly this looks fine so I have no clue where is aproblem

Comment: Maybe you could build a minimal example on http://sqlfiddle.com then we can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only care about persons belonging to an organization with no intermediate levels, then you can get the organizations using `exists`:

```
select o.*
from users o 
where exists (select 1
              from users p
              where p.parentid = o.id and
                    o.kind = 'Org' and
                    p.kind = 'Person' and
                    p.status = 'active'
             );
```

Comment: Hey, I am sorry if I confuse you but there is not 2 tables, it's just one atm

Comment: @Andurit . . . This query only refers to one table.